# Como linkar imagens em uma const para realizar a função .map() em react?

Tags: javascript, react, typescript

Estou tentando criar um array que contém os dados dos produtos que serão chamados na página através de uma função map().

Esse é o início da const, mostrando um exemplo de como eu atribuí a propriedade image.

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    image: "./images/prod1.png",
    title: "Bola Penalty",
    price: 125.0,
  },
...
```

Aqui é a parte do outro arquivo onde eu busco os dados

```
<div className="products">
          {data.map(({ id, image, title, price }) => (
            <div className="card" key={id}>
              <img src={image} alt={title} width={200} />
              <h3>{title}</h3>
              <h4>R$ {price}</h4>
              <div className="add">
                <input type="number" name="qtd" min="1" />
                <button>
                  <img src={Cart} alt="Adicionar ao carrinho" width={28} />
                  <p>Adicionar</p>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
```

O resultado está buscando todas as informações menos a imagem, pois parece que a forma de importação está incorreta, como eu deveria fazer?

Comment: Já tentou utilizar o método "require" no seu código em JavaScript? Ficaria desse modo: image: require("./images/prod1.png").

Answer (score 0):

Consegui descobrir o que estava errado, a pasta de imagens tem que ficar dentro do public, e não no src, o código estava correto.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).